# How to eliminate leading [java] label from Ant's <java> task output?

Tags: ant

I'm invoking the `<java>` task using Ant to run a program that prints out some stuff to stdout that ultimately, I'd like the user to be able to copy-paste easily. However, each line of stdout is prefixed with `[java]`, which makes things needlessly challenging for the user.

Is there some way to print **just** the output of `System.out.println(...)` without getting prefixed with `[java]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `ANT_ARGS=-emacs`, see [ant FAQ](https://ant.apache.org/faq.html#emacs-mode):

> Ant adds a "banner" with the name of the current task in front of all
>   logging messages - and there are no built-in regular expressions in
>   your editor that would account for this.
>
> ***You can disable this banner by invoking Ant with the -emacs switch.***
>   [...]

Also [ant manual Running Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#Environment) listing all cli options might be helpful :

> -emacs, -e             produce logging information without adornments

Comment: Thanks @Rebse -- while I was hoping for something I had control of *within* the Ant process, I can at least prompt the user "Hey, run again with `ANT_ARGS=-emacs` to eliminate the banner`, and it's helpful to know that it's referred to as a banner.